# Retrieve class prototype after JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, prototype, stringify

im creating in JS a Cart, whitch takes pizzas or salads, or another food products, then i save the cart in localStorage with JSON.stringify.
But when i retrieve the cart from JSON.parse, the items are simple Objects, whereas before it was an instance of Pizza, or Salad...etc

The items before:

```js
[Pizza]: {id: 1, name:"Hawaï pizza", ...}
[Pizza]: {id: 2, name:"Fresh Italian pizza", ...}
[Salad]: {id: 3, name:"Chicken Salad", ...}
```

The items after:

```js
0: {id: 1, name:"Hawaï pizza", ...}
1: {id: 2, name:"Fresh Italian pizza", ...}
2: {id: 3, name:"Chicken Salad", ...}
```

**The problem:** I have implemented some methods on each products (like Pizza.getSize() ...etc) that doesnt work after JSON.parse.

How can I retrieve that items with their original Prototypes ? Or is here a trick used to resolve that ?

Thanks

Comment: No real "trick", you need to do the prototype assigning yourself. But to do that, you need to know what type each had before you serialised it.

Comment: You can't. JSON is a serialized string from the original object, the prototype information is not included. You could add the name of the prototype to the data, that might help to add a correct prototype back to the objects. Notice, that the prototypes have to be methods of an object in order them to be able to be referred with a string (bracket notation actually).